# Mail merge functionality not working in later version of MS Word

Tags: ms-word, ole, powerbuilder, word-2007, mailmerge

We are using PowerBuilder 11.5. Mail merge was working correctly with MS Word 2005. After we switched to Word 2007, mail merge is no longer inserting fields. How can we fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are migrating the document MS Word 2005 to MS Word 2007 then, you should do the following things,

Are you using the datasource?

1. We should map the Datasource document with the Letter (I meant that word document)
2. Goto to the Word Options -> Advanced -> General -> Confirm file format conversion on Open.
3. regedit -> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Word\Options

"SQLSecurityCheck"=dword:00000000
These are the steps to execute your mailmerge funcationality in PowerBuilder